# vbscript group membership & user status

Tags: vbscript

Does anyone know how using vbscript one can query the members of a local group and also return their status ie enabled or disabled?

I have this to get the group membership:

```
Set objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
strComputer = objNetwork.ComputerName
strGroup = "Users"
Set objGroup = GetObject("WinNT://" & strComputer & "/" & strGroup & ",group")
For Each objMember In objGroup.Members
  WScript.Echo objMember.Name
Next
```

OS = Windows 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
For Each objMember In objGroup.Members
  If objMember.Class = "User" Then
    Set objUser = GetObject("WinNT://" & strComputer & "/" & objMember.Name)
    WScript.Echo objUser.Name & " [" & objUser.AccountDisabled & "]"
  Else
    WScript.Echo objMember.Name
  End If
Next
```